# How to give label for null values with previous value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table "person_visits" table have data like as below
[image]

The expected output should be like as below, the nulls should be replaced with the previous not null visited_location

[image]

Please suggest on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below i s for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(fixed_location) REPLACE(fixed_location AS visited_location) FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    LAST_VALUE(visited_location IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY calendar_date 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) fixed_location
  FROM `project.dataset.person_visits`
)
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - result is

```
Row person_id   calendar_date   visited_location    holiday_flag     
1   1001        2020-02-03      New Jersey          N    
2   1001        2020-02-04      New Jersey          N    
3   1001        2020-02-05      New Jersey          N    
4   1001        2020-02-06      New Jersey          N    
5   1001        2020-02-07      New Jersey          N    
6   1001        2020-02-08      New Jersey          Y    
7   1001        2020-02-09      New Jersey          Y    
8   1001        2020-02-10      New York            N    
9   1001        2020-02-11      New York            N    
10  1001        2020-02-12      New York            N    
11  1001        2020-02-13      New York            N    
12  1001        2020-02-14      New York            N    
13  1001        2020-02-15      New York            Y    
14  1001        2020-02-16      New York            Y    
15  1001        2020-02-17      New York            Y    
16  1001        2020-02-18      Los Angeles         N    
17  1001        2020-02-19      Los Angeles         N
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it with not exists clause

```
select a.Person_id, a.Calendar_Date, coalesce(a.Visited_Location, b.Visited_Location) as Visited_Location, a.Holiday_Flag 
from person_visits a 
left join person_visits b on a.Person_id = b.Person_id 
and a.Calendar_Date > b.Calendar_Date 
and b.Visited_Location is not null 
and not exists
(select 1 from 
person_visits c where a.Person_id = c.Person_id 
and a.Calendar_Date > c.Calendar_Date 
and c.Calendar_Date > b.Calendar_Date and c.Visited_Location is not null)
```